# Solving a SDE and finding its related moments

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am attempting to answer this multi-part question, and hope you can provide any feedback on any of my workings. My apologies for the length and thank you in advance for any help!

*i) Let $g$ be a continuous, deterministic function. Consider the SDE
$$ dX(t) = -g(t)X(t)dt + \sigma dB(t), X(0)=x$$
where $\sigma$ is a constant. Let $G(t) = \int_{0}^{t} g(s)\ ds$ so that $G'(t)= g(t)$. By letting $Y(t) = e^{G(t)}X(t)$ or otherwise solve the SDE.*

Using Ito's Lemma, I obtained:
$$ X(t) = xe^{-G(t)} + \sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{G(s) - G(t)}\ dB(s)  $$

ii) *Calculate $E[X(t)]$*
I have the stochastic integral portion of $X(t)$ satisfying a martingale, leaving the deterministic function as the mean.

$$E[X(t)] = xe^{-G(t)}$$

*iii) Let $\int_{0}^{t} e^{2G(s)} = D(t)$. Find $Var[X(t)]$ in terms of $D(t)$ for this process*

$$var[X(t)]= E\left[ \left(xe^{-G(t)} + \sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{G(s) - G(t)}\ dB(s) - xe^{-G(t)}\right)^2  \right] $$
Using Isometry property:
$$ =\sigma^2 e^{-2G(t)} \int_{0}^{t} E[e^{2G(s)}] ds = \sigma^2 e^{-2G(t)} D(t) $$

*iv) Find the moment generating function $E[e^{sX(t)}]$ for $X$:*

Using moments previously found
$$ = exp \left\{ sxe^{-G(t)} + \frac{1}{2}s^2 \sigma^2 e^{-2G(t)}  D(t)  \right\}$$

*v) Calculate $E[X(t)e^{X(t)}]$*
$$= E[X(t)]E[e^{X(t)}] = xe^{-G(t)} \times exp\left\{  xe^{-G(t)} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2e^{-G(t)}D(t) \right\}$$

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{E}[X_te^{X_t}] = \mathbb{E}[X_t]\mathbb{E}[e^{X_t}]$?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, everything seems ok except the last step. Here you have to do [Gaussian-integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502615/gaussian-integration-by-parts-proof)

$$E[g F(g)]=\sigma^{2} E[F'(g)]+\mu E[F(g)]$$

for $g\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. So you get

$$E[X(t) e^{X(t)}]= (Var(X_{t})+E[X_{t}])E[e^{X(t)}],$$

which you already computed.