# Gaussian integration by parts proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-convergence

So the result I am trying to show is that

> Lemma: (Gaussian integration by parts) Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. If $f$ is a differentiable function then
>
> $$E[f'(X)] = E[Xf(X)]$$

This is Lemma 7.2.3 in Vershynin's book, High Dimensional Probability book. If $f$ is compactly supported the proof is quite straightforward. Now to finish the proof we can approximate a general $f$ by a sequences of compactly supported functions $f_n$, but I am a little unsure of the exact details.

Issue 1: For instance is it always true we can find a sequence of compactly supported $C^1$ functions such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and whose derivatives also converges uniformly. What if we assumed $f$ is continuously differentiable then is the statement true?

Assuming we can find such functions $f_n$ then we have $E[f'_n(X)]\rightarrow E[f'(X)]$. We note that $E[f'_n(x)]=E[Xf_n(X)]$. Then since $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|f_n-f|_\infty < \epsilon$. Thus

$$\left|E[Xf_n(X)]-E[Xf(x)]\right| \leq E|Xf_n(X)-Xf(X)| \leq \epsilon E|X|$$

For $n>N$. This implies $E[f'(X)]=E[Xf(X)]$.

Comment: It surely doesn't hold for general $f$, because it may not even be defined for general $f$. Also, if $f$ does not converge to zero, there is no way of approximating it uniformly with compactly supported functions.

Comment: You do not need a uniform convergence, uniform integrability is enough. So, for example, the statement holds if $f$ satisfies $|f'(x)|\le C e^{C|x|}$ for some $C>0$.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks. Do you happen to know a reference for your statement so I can read up on the proof of why it is true?

Comment: Just write the expectation as integral and use the integration by parts.

Comment: @zhoraster The part I wanted clarification on is why does the bound $|f'(x)\leq Ce^{C|x|}$ imply that we can approximate $f$ with uniformly integrable compactly supported $C^1$ functions such that $Ef'_n(X)\rightarrow Ef'(X)$ and $EXf_n(x)\rightarrow EXf(X)$.

Comment: You don't have to use the approximation argument at all, just write the integration by parts for $f$ itself. But if you really want to go this way, use the uniform integrability: by the de la Vallée Poussin criterion, the families $\{f_n'(X), n\ge 1\}$ and $\{X f_n(X), n\ge 1\}$ are uniformly integrable.